# Python conexão Webhook problema

Tags: python, webhook

Estou com uma duvida no meu código.

Estou usando um código de exemplo e tentei aplicar para criar um modelo json na maquina local. Segue o que esta funcionando. Ele esta localizado [nesse link](
https://github.com/svet4/shipping-costs-sample):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import json
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = makeWebhookResult(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    print(res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

def makeWebhookResult(req):
    if req.get("result").get("action") != "shipping.cost":
        return {}
    result = req.get("result")
    parameters = result.get("parameters")
    zone = parameters.get("shipping-zone")

    cost = {'Europe':100, 'North America':200, 'South America':300, 'Asia':400, 'Africa':500}

    speech = "The cost of shipping to " + zone + " is " + str(cost[zone]) + " euros."

    print("Response:")
    print(speech)

    return {
        "speech": speech,
        "displayText": speech,
        #"data": {},
        # "contextOut": [],
        "source": "apiai-onlinestore-shipping"
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print "Starting app on port %d" % port

    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

---

Codigo que não funciona

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import json
import os
import firebase
import urllib3

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = makeWebhookResult(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    print(res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

def makeWebhookResult(req):

    action = req.get("result").get("action")


    if (action != "curso.valor") and (action != "translate.text") and (action !="planeta.temperatura" and (action != "pedido.gravar"):
        return {}
    result = req.get("result")
    parameters = result.get("parameters")

    # Curso

    if(action == "curso.valor"):
        curso = parameters.get("curso")

        #cost = {'R':100, 'Python':200, 'Machine Learning':300, 'Hadoop':400 }
        from firebase import firebase
        firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://dsa-bot-fabio.firebaseio.com', None)
        preco = firebase.get("/Cursos", Curso+"/Preco")

    if curso:
        speech = "O valor do curso " + curso + " e " + str(preco) + " reais."
    else:
        speech = "Qual Curso? Escolha entre: " + str(cost.keys())

     #tradução
    if(action =="translate.text"):
        text = parameters.get("text")
        language = parameters.get("to").get("lang")
        speech = text + " em " + language + " eh " + text[::-1]

    #Temperatura planeta
    if(action == "planeta.temperatura"):
        planeta = parameters.get("planeta")
        if(planeta != "Marte"):
            speech = "Ainda não medimos temperatura para " + planeta
        else:
            url="http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?format=json"
            http = urllib3.PoolManager()
            r=http.request('GET', url)
            data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
            temperatura_minima= str(data.get("Report").get("min_temp"))
            temperatura_maxima=str(data.get("Report").get("max_temp"))
            speech = "Previsao para {}: minima de {} e maxima de {}".format(planeta, temperatura_minima temperatura_maxima)

    #Gravação de pedido
    if(action =="pedido.gravar")
        from firebase import firebase
        from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication, FirebaseAuthentication


        authentication = FirebaseAuthentication('QuRhyzqXXn7s5pX2gEcdLnzC3o66mi2rmb92DcwO', True, True)
        firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://dsa-bot-fabio.firebaseio.com', authentication)

        parameters =  result.get("context")[0].get("parameters")
        nome = parameters.get("nome")
        tamanho_pao = parameters.get("tamanho_pao")
        tipo_pao = parameters.get("tipo_pao")
        recheio = parameters.get("recheio")
        queijo = "não"
        dobro_queijo = "não"
        if(parameters.get("dobro_queijo")):
            queijo = "sim"
            dobro_queijo = parameters.get("dobro_queijo")

        pedido = {"nome": nome, "tamanho_pao": tamanho_pao, "tipo_pao": tipo_pao, "queijo": queijo, "dobro_queijo": dobro_queijo, "recheio": recheio}
        result = firebase.post("/Pedidos", pedido)
        speech = "Anote seu pedido: {}. Volte sempre!".format(result['name'])







    print("Response:")
    print(speech)

    return {
        "speech": speech,
        "displayText": speech,
        #"data": {},
        # "contextOut": [],
        "source": "apiai-onlinestore-shipping"
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print ("Starting app on port %d" % port)

    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

O Erro que surge para mim é o seguinte:

```
File "C:\Users\fabio\dsa-bot-fabio\app.py", line 37
if (action != "curso.valor") and (action != "translate.text") and (action !="planeta.temperatura" and (action != "pedido.gravar"):

^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

O erro é claro, causado por algo traiçoeiro:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Nesta linha:

```
File "C:\Users\fabio\dsa-bot-fabio\app.py", line 37
if (action != "curso.valor") and (action != "translate.text") and (action !="planeta.temperatura" and (action != "pedido.gravar"):
```

possivelmente este `if` está indentado com símbolos diferentes dos demais. Por exemplo, a indentação do arquivo é feita com 4 espaços, mas você usou <kbd>tab</kbd> na linha.

Alguns editores possuem a opção de trocar todo comando <kbd>tab</kbd> por espaços para evitar este erro. Seria bom habilitar essa opção.

Em todo caso, apague a indentação da linha e a faça de novo. Se falhar com <kbd>tab</kbd>, faça apenas usando espaços.

---

Corrigindo no Sublime Text:

- View -> Indentation
- Onde diz

  - *Indent using spaces* [x]
  - *Tab width*: 2
- Desmarque *Convert Indentation to Tabs*

  - *Tab width*: 4
  - *Convert Indentation to Spaces*

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> para reindentar o código.

Comment: Mas estranho dar esse problema, sendo que no outro código o espaçamento é o mesmo não? Eu estou usando o sublime para rodar o código.

Comment: Pois é. Veja minha edição se te ajuda.